# What exactly does the .(dot) operator do in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, pointers, dot-operator

I taught myself C and C++ and am trying to learn Objective-C now, but I am a little confused by the dot operator used on instances of classes. Say I declared a class:

```
MyClass* myinstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];

//Then I call the member function foo:

myinstance.foo;
```

Obviously this works in Objective-C, but in C++ or C (in the case of a struct), this wouldn't. You would have to use the operator ->. So I'm looking for an explanation of what exactly the .(dot) operator does in Objective-C and how the two different meanings from ObjC and C don't cause compatibility issues between C and Objective-C even though Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot notation is to call the method as we do it by using space. we can call methods by using space with all variables but dot notation is used with property and synthesizes variables only

example

```
 variable.method_name; //is a dot notation with property and synthesized variable
[variable method_name]; // is space notation
```

and the dot notation is for all default properties because those are already property and synthesized like

```
label.text = @"Ashok";
```

and  as said space can be used by synthesizing separately using set method as

```
[label setText:@"Ashok"];
```

ThanQ

Comment: "space notation"? That's a new one.  It is typically called "bracketed call" or "bracket notation", but I kinda dig "space notation", too.

Comment: Or you can say obj-c style for "space notation", and c-style for "dot notation"

Comment: ThnQ Anoop but my clarification is also correct right

Comment: now your answer is incorrect, if I read your first commented code... `.` work even for both.

Comment: Yes you are right Anoop thnQ